# adding multiple values to single array item in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

I am having trouble with output of an array, I think.

What I would like the output to look like is:

```
1. FirstName LastName DOB
```

but what I end up with is:

```
1. FirstName
2. LastName
3. DOB
```

Here is what I have so far but I am not seeing what I am doing wrong.

```
// global variable:
var tasks = []; 

// Function called when the form is submitted.
// Function adds a task to the global array.
function addTask() {
    'use strict';

    // Get the task:
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
    var dob = document.getElementById('dob');

    // numerical value of dob
    var dateofBirth = new Date(dob.value);

    // Reference to where the output goes:
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    // For the output:
    var message = '';

    if (firstName.value && lastName.value && dob.value) {

        // Add the item to the array:
        tasks.push(firstName.value, lastName.value, dateofBirth.toString());


        // Update the page:
        message = '<h2>Persons Entered</h2><ol>';
        for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
            message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + '</li>';
        }
        message += '</ol>';
        output.innerHTML = message;

    } // End of IF.

    // Return false to prevent submission:
    return false;

} // End of addTask() function.

// Initial setup:
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addTask;
} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

Thanks, I hope this helps you to help me.

Comment: Because <li> are positioned vertically by default. You have to change your css about the <ol> <li> attribute with display: inline;
list-style-type: none; if you want it to be horizontal without bullet point.

Or, put them in the same <li>

Comment: You should change your approach to begin with. This is a typical misuse of `.innerHTML`. Every time you add a new task, you're destroying the old ones and recreating them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tasks.push({firstName: firstName.value, lastName: lastName.value, DOB: dateofBirth.toString()})
```

And then

```
tasks[0].firstName will output firstName.value
tasks[0].lastName will output lastName.value
```

etc..

Edit

Using this, you can then construct your messasge like this :

```
for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
    message += '<li><span>' + tasks[i].firstName + '</span><span> ' 
    + tasks[i].lastName + '</span><span>' + tasks[i].DOB + '</span></li>';
}
```

Of course, the span tags are optionnal but this will allow you to apply a style to each part of the information in your css (width, padding, etc..) and you will always be able to easily select a property of a task by index

Comment: This does not answer his question. He seems to be aware of how to use arrays

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're adding `li` elements to every element in your array, instead only add teh li once

```
    // Update the page:
    message = '<h2>Persons Entered</h2><ol><li>' + tasks.join(' ') + '</li></ol>';
    output.innerHTML = message;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put each element in its own `<li>`?

If you don't put it in different `<li>` but in a common one, everything will be fine

```
message = '<h2>Persons Entered</h2><ol><li>';

        for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
            message += tasks[i];
            message += " ";
        }
        message += '</li></ol>';
        output.innerHTML = message;
```

Comment: This will result in ```firstNamelastNameDOB``` all jumbled together

Comment: Yes you are right, but I think this is not really the biggest point here. I upvoted your answer which is a lot cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Span. you can use Array.join

```
output.innerHTML= '<h2>Persons Entered</h2><div><span>' + tasks.join("</span> <span>") +"</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add them as an array to the array, not as values to the array

What you have is this:

```
tasks.push(firstName.value, lastName.value, dateofBirth.toString());
```

what I think you want is this:

```
tasks.push([firstName.value, lastName.value, dateofBirth.toString()]);
```

The answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219375/565514) is the same, but with an object, not a array.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is pushing multiple values into your array. What you want to be doing is to turn the different values into a single value and then push that value into your array. To get the exact output as you were requesting, you can turn these multiple values into one by concatenating them into a string:

Change this:

```
tasks.push(firstName.value, lastName.value, dateofBirth.toString());
```

Into this:

```
tasks.push(firstName.value + ' ' + lastName.value + ' ' + dateofBirth.toString());
```

However, this does mean you'll lose access to the individual values. If you want access to those, you could instead assemble them into an object:

```
tasks.push({"firstName" : firstName.value,
            "lastName" : lastName.value,
            "dateOfBirth" : dateofBirth.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a little confusing what you are asking. If you simply want this:

```
1. FirstName LastName DOB
```

over this:

```
1. FirstName
2. LastName
3. DOB
```

Then your issue is not with the array but with how you are defining the loop code. Try this instead:

```
// Update the page:
message = '<h2>Persons Entered</h2><ol><li>';
for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
    message += tasks[i] + ' ';
}
message += '</li></ol>';
```

That way you are putting the array elements in a single list element, rather than across three of them.

---

**EDIT - for Multi-dimensional array traversal**

This is assuming that the array is defined this way (per [Dan Steingart's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219397/705055) answer):

```
tasks.push([firstName.value, lastName.value, dateofBirth.toString()]);
```

We then can have the following:

```
// Update the page:
message = '<h2>Persons Entered</h2><ol>';

for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
    message += '<li> + tasks[i].toString().replace(',',' ') + '</li>';
}

message += '</ol>';
```

Here you are traversing each element of `tasks` when each element of `tasks` is also itself an array. The `toString()` on an inner array will display the values in a comma separated fashion, then the `replace()` function simply replaces the comma's with spaces.

Comment: I'm trying to output more than one. 1. FirstName LastName DOB directly under it 2. FirstName LastName DOB etc....

Comment: With your code, you are only defining the array to hold one set of values. You can follow some of the other suggestions here for adding other sets of values. @DanSteingarts answer gives an acceptable way of doing this. I will edit my response to include a multi-dimenional array traversal